# Kids with a cloak who freeze time, whereupon goblins can move

Tags: story-identification, movie

My son keeps asking what this movie was. I kinda remember watching it but can't find it anywhere!! Here's what I know:

There are kids with a cloak, I think, that can freeze time. When they freeze time, goblins can move but that's the ONLY time these goblins/creatures can move. They go into a forest and there is something about this tree. That's all I remember!!

I hope someone can help with this!!!

Comment: Damn, I was about to answer this, but then I realised I can't remember the name of the book I'm thinking of to check whether it had a film adaptation! Were there two kids, a boy and a girl, who are agents for some kind of time travel organisation? Do they have a sinister enemy called something like Midnight who controls these goblin creatures?

Comment: Could this be the execrable "Troll 2"? It had time-stopping, goblins and forest scenes; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igH2v8NFm9I

Comment: It's not trolls 2, it's newer than that. My son is 8 so it has to be around this time.  I don't think they were in an agency. I just think some friends stumbled across this thing that had magic and could freeze time. The goblins can't move until time is frozen and they are coming after the kids to get the "cloak" I assume.  It's driving me crazy that I can't think of it or remember more.

Comment: It was a couple of years ago that we watched it. I have tried "Spiderwick Chronicles" but that's not it. Not "Clockstoppers".  They kids, friends,  were younger... Maybe 13.

Comment: How sure are you about the words you're using? Was it specifically a "***cloak***", were the monsters specifically "***goblins***", for example.

Comment: Also, can you please work your way through the checklists [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question). For example, what ages were the kids? What genders were the kids?

Answer (score 2):

Could it be an episode of Deadtime Stories rather than a movie?  There is an episode called [Revenge of the Goblins](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2814882/).

The premise is very similar to what you remember, except that rather than a cloak, there is a luminous ball that can stop time, when time is stopped, the Goblins can move.  The tree that you remember is early on, the kids find a strange door in a tree, and on opening it they find what appears to be a statue holding the ball.

IIRC there are 2 goblins, one evil and another trying to get the ball back so that the door to the goblin world can be shut again.

The episode was broadcast in 2013, so it is new.